# angular ngOnInit() whith HttpClient , the asynchronous get json data to typescript data

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-template

when I set the `HttpClient`(this.http) to get data in `ngOnInit()`:

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/getData').subscribe((data) => {
      const type = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('type');
      this.theme = data;
      this.side = this.theme.find((item, index, array) => {
        return item.router == type;
      });
}
```

`this.side` is a node.js back a json object and `find` some condition  like this:

```
{
  PhotoUrl: 'abc.jpg',
  Title: 'title',
  Router:'router',
}
```

when I setting in `this.side` template:

```
<div class="side-photo">
    <img src="{{side.PhotoUrl}">
</div>
<div class="side-photo">
    {{side.Title}}
</div>
```

These parameters can be displayed normally on the web page.
Like `<img src="{{side.PhotoUrl}">` pictures can be displayed normally.
But the chrome console shows a lot of errors like this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read
property 'PhotoUrl' of undefined
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14689)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13803)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14149)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14081)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13804)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14149)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14107)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13799)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14149)
```

`PhotoUrl,Title,Router` These have similar errors.
I don't know this is an asynchronous issue or a typescript issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're trying to render the template with a variable that doesn't have a value yet (because REST call resolves *way after* your template is rendered), as the error suggests.

Try using the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) `?.` on the source attribute:

```
<div class="side-photo">
    <img [src]="side?.PhotoUrl" />
</div>
<div class="side-photo">
    {{side?.Title}}
</div>
```

Another common pattern is to wrap the whole DOM fragment that requires that variable with a check for the variable, like:

```
<ng-content *ngIf="side">
    <div class="side-photo">
        <img [src]="side.PhotoUrl" />
    </div>
    <div class="side-photo">
        {{side.Title}}
    </div>
</ng-content>
```

See [`<ng-content />`](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content), but any element works: choose based on your use-case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** try to `console.log()` something after subscribe and check if error happens  before or after `console.log`

If it happens before, it's an **async** error and you should consider using some `route resolver` to get data before route is loaded or just make the property optional `side?.photoUrl`

Comment: `?.` does not "make the property optional"

Comment: Not at all, see the link in my answer. "Optional property" refers to a type interface or class (which lives at compile-time within the type-checker) where as `?.` is a _run-time_ property accessor that doesn't blow up if it's undefined.

Comment: Oh ok .Didn't know about this !!

Comment: They sort of feel similar, I admit, but their behaviour is _very_ different. :) Always happy to share.

Answer (score 0):

You could initalise side.photourl with a default url during initialisation. That way you wouldn't get undefined in the src of the image when it first renders.

It's an asynchronous issue as you suggested